# Error: grecaptcha is not defined for google recaptcha version 2

Tags: javascript, jquery, recaptcha

I am implementing google recaptcha version 2.
Here, the site-key which is used is coming from another API call from backend.

```
<div class="form-group">
   <div id="captcha_container"></div>
</div>

<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?render=explicit"></script>
```

There is an ajax which bring different data, one of the data is site-key value for the captcha.

```
$.ajax({
    url : url,
    type : 'GET',
    headers : {
        "cache-control" : "no-cache"
    },
    success : function(data) {
       const siteKeyValue = data.siteKey;
       if(siteKeyValue) {
         grecaptcha.render('captcha_container', {
           'sitekey' : siteKeyValue
         });
       }
    }
});
```

The code works and load the captcha but after 2-3 reload I get the error saying **"grecaptcha is not defined"**.

I tried the solution of other stack question where loading the script and then executing like this but, it didn't work.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $.getScript( "https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?render=explicit", 
   function() {
      grecaptcha.render('captcha_container', {
         'sitekey' : siteKeyValue
      });
   });
</script>
```

Adding setTimeout works but I don't think it is a good solution

```
setTimeout(function() {
  grecaptcha.render('captcha_container', {
     'sitekey' : siteKeyValue
  });
}, 1000);
```

I don't want to use the onload method in script tag as my ajax function do other things as well.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved when I moved the script tag below the reCaptcha div, instead of placing it inside the head tag like google said.But its works.